# Can't get which query loads contents

Tags: json, ajax, networking, developer-tools

I'm trying to grab applications' update timeline from mobileaction.co, but I got a problem here.
They got one trial app for two platforms.

Grabbing IOS versions was easy:

> I just went to this one https://insights.mobileaction.co/appupdatetimeline?trackId=571800810&regionCode=US, and found query using developer tools to https://dashboard.mobileaction.co/app/571800810/US/app-update-timeline, which returns json response of timeline.

But Android is not so easy

> Then I tried to find identical link for android, but I can't do it.
>   I went to https://insights.mobileaction.co/appupdatetimeline?trackId=com.calm.android&regionCode=US, but I can't find where it loads all the versions list from.

I think, I should get trackId for android app and it is gonna be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link is https://dashboard.mobileaction.co/app/{package_name}/en/app-update-timeline